# Need help using glRasterPos3f (openGL)

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, opengl-compat

I'm trying to create a game using OpenGL. My game works quite well but i wanted to add a score. There, two problems appeared :

- The screen started shining (i think it's a problem of the position in the code of `glutPostRedisplay()`)
- The score is moving on the screen

If you have any idea about how i could repare this feel free to answer :D.

code of the function that displays the score :

```cpp
void drawBitmapText(char *string) {  
    char *c;    
    glRasterPos3f(1,1,-1);
    for (c=string; *c != '\0'; c++) {
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_10, *c);
    }
}

void AffichageScore(void){ 
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
    glLoadIdentity();
    std::string scoreSTR = std::to_string(score);
    scoreSTR = "Score : "+scoreSTR;
    int len = scoreSTR.length();
    char scoreArray[len+1];
    std::strcpy(scoreArray, scoreSTR.c_str()); 
    drawBitmapText(scoreArray);
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates which are set by [`glRasterPos`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRasterPos.xml) are transformed by the the current modelview and projection matrices.

Use [`glWindowPos`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glWindowPos.xml) which directly updates the x and y coordinates of the current raster position and does not apply the current modelview and projection matrices. But note, the coordinates to `glWindowPos` have to be window coordinates:

```cpp
void drawBitmapText(char *string) {  
    char *c;    

    glWindowPos3f(0, 0, 0);

    for (c=string; *c != '\0'; c++) {
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_10, *c);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you set the the current matrices by the [Identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) when `glRasterPos` is called:

```cpp
void drawBitmapText(char *string) {  

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();

    glRasterPos3f(1,1,-1);

    char *c;   
    for (c=string; *c != '\0'; c++) {
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_10, *c);
    }

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPopMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```